# Monero withdrawal from Bitfinex to Binance sent 12+ hours ago

Tags: blockchain

I sent XMR from Bitfinex to Binance +12 hours ago. Till now there is no deposit on Binance. I have checked the TXID: 839b6483537cafb3fa7663cc89d45162c06669a670a5c864fb477073d95b6359

I can not find any information about this TXID. Bitfinex says that the withdrawal is completed:

[image: withdrawal info]

What can I do now?

I have entered the address and the payment id which Binance provided me. I think the failure must be on Bitfinex side because there is no transaction info.

Comment: There's not much you can do if you sent from exchange to exchange except for contacting the support of both exchanges.